# phonegap desktop app connect to my laptop's server

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, server, phonegap-desktop-app

Hi I am using the phonegap desktop app to make hybrid iphone apps. I had my app download on my iphone device but it can't connect to my localhost on my laptop becausue they are two different machines. I want to know how to connect to my laptop's local server from my actual iphone device. Don't give me answers if you don't actually know if it works.

Comment: Are you trying to use your app to make server side requests on your laptop's local server?